# Global array brackets gets removed after compiling in chelper intelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using chelper with intelliJ and the brackets gets removed after compilation. Is there any solution to this?

Here's what my code looks before compilation:

```
public class TaskA {
    int arr[];
    public void solve(int testNumber, InputReader in, OutputWriter out) {
        arr = new int[3];

    }
}
```

and Here's how it looks after compilation:

```
static class TaskA {
        int arr;

        public void solve(int testNumber, InputReader in, OutputWriter out) {
            arr = new int[3];

        }

    }
```

It also gives this error:

> Error:(32, 19) java: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using brackets before the variable name and it should work fine.

```
public class TaskA {
    int[] arr;
    public void solve(int testNumber, InputReader in, OutputWriter out) {
        arr = new int[3];

    }
}
```

Here's a link of Egor talking about why this needs to be done. http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/18974?#comment-357444.